# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes domain global

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-apis-explorer, androidpublisher

to check inapp purchase i have used this api [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/products/%7BproductId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D) and got this response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Insufficient Permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "androidpublisher.ProductPurchasesService.Get",
                    "service": "androidpublisher.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're running an application from a compute instance or GKE you may have a problem with the *scopes* of that *instance* (as distinct from the IAM roles assigned to the service account the application is run with). Hard to find a general documation page for it, but look at the `--scopes` arg for `gcloud compute instances create`. Documentation for a similar problem in secret manager is [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control).

Comment: You may just need to add `--scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"` (or whatever scope you're missing)

Answer (score 21):

By any chance, have you been invoking this from a GCE VM? If so, you might want to:

1. Stop the VM
2. Go to the GCE VM instances in the cloud console
3. Click edit on the machine
4. Go to scopes
   [image]
5. Edit the scopes as desired (preferably adding the scope just to a particular API or if you are OK with it - to all APIs, depending on context and risk)
6. Restart the machine and make the API call again

Some useful references can be found [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Security/Role-Permission-s-for-Getting-PolicyTag-Information/td-p/175593) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam).

Answer (score 0):

By chance are you missing full user name in you Authorisation flow `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize(_USER_ID + "@gmail.com");`